# Set predefined range of a counter in Tabletop Simulator

Tags: lua, tabletop-simulator

Trying to limit the amount that the counter can be set at in Tabletop Simulators Counter Object using LUA.  Would like the minus button to deactivate at 1.  After reading through the API source I can't seem to find my answer.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know TTS but from the manual I get that a button has a `interactable` attribute.
You can also get the value of a counter using its `getValue` method.

So whenever you decrement the counter value check the value. If it equals `1` set the `interactable` attribute of that button to `false` using `setAttribute`

Comment: I am not sure I put it in the right spot, but this did not work in the way I tried.  I posted the full code in the answer below.

Comment: @RhinoTekMN you're not using the things I suggested in your code so I can't tell you what went wrong.

Answer (score 0):

A friendly person from reddit came to the rescue.

````
    if dice_Quantity < 1 then
        broadcastToAll("You can't roll less than 1 die")
        watchingDice = false
    return```
````

Answer (score 0):

The button presumably calls a click handler which subtracts one from a variable and update the displayed value when clicked.

You haven't shown your code --you haven't even specified if you're talking about Lua-created buttons or XML-created buttons-- but it would look something like this:

```lua
function on_minus_button_clicked()
   val = val - 1
   update_ui()
end
```

You simply need to add a check to prevent it from going negative.

```lua
function on_minus_button_clicked()
   if val == 0 then
      return
   end

   val = val - 1
   update_ui()
end
```